# socke.io could not connect to flashsocket?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I upgraded from socket.io 1.3.3, and force socket.io to connect to flash socket.

```
socketObj = io('http://localhost:9090', {'transports' : ['flashsocket'],'reconnection delay': 20});
```

I'm getting the following messages on console.

```
socket.io.js:199 connect attempt will timeout after 20000
socket.io.js:324 attempting reconnect
socket.io.js:199 connect attempt will timeout after 20000
socket.io.js:324 attempting reconnect
socket.io.js:199 connect attempt will timeout after 20000
socket.io.js:324 attempting reconnect
socket.io.js:199 connect attempt will timeout after 20000
socket.io.js:324 attempting reconnect
socket.io.js:199 connect attempt will timeout after 20000
socket.io.js:324 attempting reconnect
```

I'm using `Chrome version 43.0.2357.125`. Please tell me either it's browser creating issue or it's socket.io bug? Or it's me who mis-configuring something.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect without reconnection delay or transport.Just only with host

Comment: can you please explain, without transport?

Comment: i tried to reconnect without resonnetion delay, but still having the same problem.

Comment: in that case, socket.io connected to xhr-polling only.